# Case Expression inside where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have found a few posts that were very similar to what I am wanting to do, but it didn't seem to work.  I have this case in my select:

```
case 
        when h.Posted_Flag=-1 and h.Returned_Flag=0 then 'Posted'
        when h.Posted_Flag=0 then 'Unposted'
        when h.Returned_Flag=1 and h.Posted_Flag=-1 then 'Returned'
        when h.Returned_Flag = 2 then 'Partial Return'
        else '*****'
end as Return_Status,
```

I would like to place this in my where clause and equal to a variable I have set:

```
Declare @TicketStatus nvarchar
set @TicketStatus = 'Returned'

and @TicketStatus=(case 
            when h.Posted_Flag=-1 and h.Returned_Flag=0 then 'Posted'
            when h.Posted_Flag=0 then 'Unposted'
            when h.Returned_Flag=1 and h.Posted_Flag=-1 then 'Returned'
            when h.Returned_Flag = 2 then 'Partial Return'
            end)
```

When I try to run what I have, I get no records returned, when I run this without the AND(case) there are many Retunred Status's with Returned in them.

any help would be great.

thanks
BD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a problem with how you declared your variable. What happens if you do this?

```
Declare @TicketStatus nvarchar
set @TicketStatus = 'Returned'

SELECT @TicketStatus
```

The returned value is `'R'`, not `'Returned'`, this happens because you didn't give a length to your variable. You should do this:

```
Declare @TicketStatus nvarchar(15)
set @TicketStatus = 'Returned'
```

Comment: Wow, cant believe that was it.  This is the first time I have used declarations, I should have read a little more into it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the condition?

```
h.Returned_Flag=1 and h.Posted_Flag=-1
```

Comment: OP (probably) wants to select one of many conditions based on a variable.

Comment: In which case you should ask for clarification!

Comment: @SalmanA I was rather hoping my answer might precipitate some such.

Comment: Yeah should have included that, just thought have I had it written was proof enough. thanks